# how to hide airplay popup after selecting an airplay device?

Tags: swift, airplay

I have managed to display airplay popup that displays a list of available airplay devices, when I select a device from the list of available device, I want to dismiss the popup. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no way of doing this using code, you have to do it manually by tapping anywhere outside the popup.